# Next.js: What to do if a child process doesn't have any data to return?

Tags: node.js

I'm using Next.js to pipe system calls. The code looks *something like* this (not *exactly* this, but this is simple enough to illustrate what I'm doing):

```
export async function find(file, searchTerm) {

    const cat = execFile('cat', [file], {maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024});
    const grep = execFile('grep', [searchTerm], {maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024});
    cat.stdout.pipe(grep.stdin);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        grep.stdout.on('data', async (d) => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve(d.toString().trim()), 100)
        });
    });
}
```

Notice there are two processes:

- `cat`
- `grep`

`cat.stdout` is piped to `grep.stdin`, and when `grep.stdout` receives `data`, the whole function returns a `Promise`.

All fine and good. The problem is that if `grep` **doesn't** find `searchTerm` inside the results returned from `cat`, the callback for `grep.stdout.on('data', ...` isn't invoked and the whole chain just hangs.

In production I have an abstraction that lets me chain together an arbitrary number of processes (started with `execFile` as above).

Is there a way to detect if any process in the chain returns "nothing", and to just send "nothing" (e.g. the empty string) along the pipe?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the end event on stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the on 'exit' event here.

> The 'exit' event is emitted after the child process ends. If the
>   process exited, code is the final exit code of the process, otherwise
>   null. If the process terminated due to receipt of a signal, signal is
>   the string name of the signal, otherwise null. One of the two will
>   always be non-null.

So you can reject the **promise** when this event is occurred.

more info : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [`process.exit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) function in the callback, Like this:

```js
const { execFile } = require('child_process');

async function find(file, searchTerm) {

    const cat = execFile('cat', [file], {maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024});
    const grep = execFile('grep', [searchTerm], {maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      //Because grep gives an empty string when no match
      if(stdout ===''){
        console.log('emptty')
        process.exit()
      }
    });
    cat.stdout.pipe(grep.stdin)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        grep.stdout.on('data', async (d) => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve(d.toString().trim()), 100)
        });
    })
    .then(d => console.log('succes'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is this, for all processes in the chain, I added the following event listener:

```
p.on('close', (code) => {
    if (code > 0) {
        reject(`child process PID ${p.pid} exited with code ${code}`);
    }
});
```

If the exit code of any of the processes isn't `0` (`0` means no errors), reject the `Promise`.